# How can I read a dmp file in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, crash

I have a dmp file as the result of a chrome crash, what can I use to read it on windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WinDBG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) will allow you to get quite a bit of information on what happened - though usage is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) by NirSoft can read .dmp files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the suggested WinDbg. Here are some Videos how to use it:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-13-WinDbg

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-16-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-17-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier-Part-2

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-18-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier-Part-3

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-20-WinDbg-Basic-Commands

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-22-WinDbg-Memory-Kernel-Mode